# multidimensional data clustering

Tags: multidimensional-array, cluster-analysis

Problem: I have two groups of multidimensional heterogeneous data. I have concocted a simple illustrative example below. Notice that some columns are discrete (age) while some are binary (gender) and another is even an ordered pair (pant size).

```
Person         Age  gender   height     weight  pant_size
Control_1      55   M        167.6      155     32,34
Control_2      68   F        154.1      137     28,28
Control_3      53   F        148.9      128     27,28
Control_4      57   M        167.6      165     38,34
Control_5      62   M        147.4      172     36,32
Control_6      44   M        157.6      159     32,32
Control_7      76   F        172.1      114     30,32
Control_8      49   M        161.8      146     34,34
Control_9      53   M        164.4      181     32,36

Person         Age  gender   height     weight  pant_size
experiment_1   39   F        139.6      112     26,28
experiment_2   52   M        154.1      159     32,32
experiment_3   43   F        148.9      123     27,28
experiment_4   55   M        167.6      188     36,38
experiment_5   61   M        161.4      171     36,32
experiment_6   48   F        149.1      144     28,28
```

The question is does the entire experimental group differ significantly from the entire control group?

Or roughly speaking do they form two distinct clusters in the space of [age,gender,height,weight,pant_size]?

The general idea of what I’ve tried so far is a metric that compares corresponding columns of the experimental group to those of the control; the metric then takes the sum of the column scores (see below). A somewhat arbitrary threshold is picked to decide if the two groups are different. This arbitrariness is confounded by the weighting of the columns which is also somewhat arbitrary. Remarkably this approaches is preforming well for the actual problem I have but it needs to be formalized. I’m wondering if this approach is similar to any existing approaches or if other well established approaches more widely accepted?

```
Person         Age  gender   height     weight  pant_size
experiment_1   39   F        139.6      112     26,28
experiment_2   52   M        154.1      159     32,32
experiment_3   43   F        148.9      123     27,28
experiment_4   55   M        167.6      188     36,38
experiment_5   61   M        161.4      171     36,32
experiment_6   48   F        149.1      144     28,28        metric

column score   2    1        5          1       7            16
```

Comment: Since it is possible that some columns might be different between control and experiment, and some might not, you could try the two-sample T-test (or some variation of it) to test whether or not each variable with respect to the two groups has a significant difference. For the categorical variable (gender), you could do a test of proportions to see if either group has more or less females/males.  Chi-squared test on gender variable could also be used I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat this as a **classification** rather than a clustering problem if you assume the results "cluster".

Because you don't need to find these clusters, but they are predefined classes.

The "rewritten" approach is as follows:

Train different classifiers to **predict whether a point is from data A or data B**. If you can get a much better accuracy than 50% (assuming balanced data) then the geoups do differ. If all your classifiers are only as good as random (and you didn't make mistakes) then tthe two sets are probably just too similar.